# Program Dependence Graphs (PDG)

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am new to LLVM and I need to analyse the program (Control flow and Data flow analysis). I couldn't find PDG or Task Graph in LLVM. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool to build an inter-procedural program dependence graph in LLVM:
https://bitbucket.org/psu_soslab/program-dependence-graph-in-llvm/src/master/

Answer (score 1):

The detail procedure is available here (take note you have to download LLVM 9.0.0 for this to work, from https://releases.llvm.org/download.html, choose according to your preferred platform):

https://github.com/tthtlc/my_llvm_program_dependency_generator

The example hello.c inside is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the program dependency graph is here:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you look at this link: http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#ViewGraph (the "Viewing graphs while debugging code" section) it talks about how to generate and view graphs using graphviz. This is useful for both interactive use as well as for creating graphs for publication.

Comment: LLVM does not have PDG. Yet.

Comment: @JohnTortugo sure, but the question seems to be asking about graphs for control flow and data flow analysis in general (mentions "new to LLVM", and "need to analyze the program") for which the currently supported types of CFGs LLVM currently can spit out into graphviz are certainly VERY helpful.